# How to mock server response using chai, sinon and mocha

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, mocha.js, sinon, chai

I recently wrote a small service which

1. makes an http request to an xml file containing service definitions,
2. converts the responded from `xml` to `json` and parses the `json` for given key
3. returns an object if the given key was found,
4. otherwise an empty array

### Related code

```
resolve() {
    return this._makeResolveRequest() // 1.
        .then(this._convertServiceList) // 2. and 3.
        .then(serviceList => this._filterServices(serviceList)); // 4.
}
```

`this._makeResolveRequest` returns a promise.

```
_makeResolveRequest() {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        return request(options, function (error, response, body) {
            if(error) {
                reject(error);
            }
            resolve(body);
        })
    });
}
```

### Testing

Now I got really stuck in writing my tests and I've clearly no idea where to start.

I want to test the actual implementation and verify that the chained methods are working properly together. So my test should make a real http request but the response should be mocked. The mocked response should pass all "stations". At the end I expect an object based on the provided mock data.

```
describe("Arguments", function () {

  it("the service should be a string", function () {
    expect(resolver.serviceType).to.be.a('string');
  });

  it("configuration should be a object", function () {
    expect(resolver.options).to.be.a('object');
  });

  it("configuration should have a attribute protocol", function () {
    expect(resolver.options).to.have.property('protocol');
  });

  it("configuration should have a attribute host", function () {
    expect(resolver.options).to.have.property('host');
  });

  it("configuration have a attribute port", function () {
    expect(resolver.options).to.have.property('port');
  });

  it('should use all passed options', function () {
    // .catch() is used here as we do not have a server running
    // which responds properly
    resolver.resolve().catch(function (err) {
      expect(err.options.uri).to.equal('http://localhost:1234/tr64desc.xml');
      expect(err.options.uri).not.to.equal('https://localhost:1234/tr64desc.xml');
      expect(err.options.uri).not.to.equal('https://localhost/tr64desc.xml');
      expect(err.options.uri).not.to.equal('http://lorem.com/tr64desc.xml');
    })
  });

});
```

### The Problem starts here

```
describe("Service Resolver", function () {
    let resolver = new ServiceResolver('CommonInterfaceService', {
        protocol: 'http',
        host: 'localhost',
        port: '1234'
    });

    it('should return an object of CommonInterfaceService if the was available', function () {
        resolver.resolve() //??
    });
});
```

This results obviously in the following error, because there is no server running which responds the requested xml file.

```
{ [Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:1234]
  code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  errno: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  syscall: 'connect',
  address: '127.0.0.1',
  port: 1234 }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use "[nock](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nock)" to mock out the server request + response (you can set what response code and body should be returned).

More of a tutorial here: https://davidwalsh.name/nock

Hope that helps!

Comment: Yes :) I came across `nock` a few moments ago :)